# Abelianization of the free product of two cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G=G_1*G_2$ where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cyclic of orders $m$ and $n$ respectively.  Show that $G/[G,G]$ has order $mn$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show that the order is at most $mn$?

Comment: that is easy...but it isn't that trivial to show that the order is exactly mn.

Comment: For that direction, find a group with order $mn$ which satisfies the three relations you have.

Comment: I guess that way is to construct a homomorphism from G to that group and use the isomorphism theorem...but I wasn't able to show that the kernel of the homomorphism equals [G,G].

Comment: oh, wait a sec..

Comment: I got an idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

**A categorical solution**: Abelization is left adjoint to forgetting commutativity and therefore commutes with colimits. Since $G\ast H$ is a coproduct of groups, and $G\oplus H$ is a coproduct of abelian groups, we have $$A(G_1\ast G_2)\cong A(G_1)\oplus A(G_2)\cong G_1\oplus G_2\,,$$where the last step follows from commutativity of cyclic groups (this concept has a name, $\mathbf{Ab}$ is a *reflective subcategory* of $\mathbf{Grp}$). Of course, $A$ denotes the abelization functor.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** Let $G=\langle a, b; a^n, b^m\rangle$. Then the abelianisation of $G$ has presentation $\langle a, b; a^n, b^m, [a, b]\rangle$.

**Hint 2:** The group $G/H$ is abelian if and only if the map $G\rightarrow G/H$ factors through the quotient $G/[G, G]$.